# What all are the possible reporting deployment options?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have a small application where there are some reports i have done. What i do each time when i have to deploy the reports is as follows,

1. take the solution of the reporting to the sql machine where reporting server is installed
2. open the solution change the data source property and sql reporting server url then say deploy.

Is there other better way like more nice so that it can be given to end user and he can do it on his own by configuring the data sounce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of other options are:

- [Upload the file with Report Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157332.aspx)
- Write a [script to publish reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa179216) using the [rs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa179659(v=SQL.80).aspx) utility

Comment: Is there something like we just combine the files together as a deplyable component and just give it to client for click/configure and click for report deployment. Or something similar that we can do with ASP.NET site for site deployment?

Comment: I'm not aware of any tools to do that. You'd have to write custom code exploiting the ReportsOperationsCollection class as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reportingservices.interfaces.reportoperation(SQL.90).aspx